# How to use scons compile different folder source codes

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I have source code and the code need reference other folder library (*.o).

I can use makefile to compile other folder source code then generate and link the library file  in liunx system.

How to operating same compile flow in scons?

Please help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to list source files from different directories together in one list.  In my case, I have the build.scons file in the top level directory, then source and test files in subdirectories, like this:

```
build.scons
src/
 |
  -> random.cc
test/
 |
  -> test.cc
```

Here is a snippet from my build.scons that works:

```
import make_nacl_env
import nacl_utils
import os

nacl_env = make_nacl_env.NaClEnvironment(use_c_plus_plus_libs=True)
nacl_env.Append(
    CPPPATH=[os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))],
    CCFLAGS=['-Wall', '-Wno-long-long', '-pthread', '-Werror', '-std=c++0x'],
   )

sources = ['test/test.cc',
           'src/random.cc']

nacl_env.AllNaClModules(sources, 'myproject')
```